# List out inserted External Memory Directory Name on Android Tv?

Tags: android, google-tv

`Android-TV` has 2 or more USB ports. I need to list out the available usb driver name. User can choose any one of the USB device name, I want to list out the list of file by usb name selection.

Comment: First I need to listout available external device elements.How to list out available external memory elements

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115317/how-can-you-access-external-memory-on-google-tv

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)

especially the code

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
...  
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
UsbDevice device = deviceList.get("deviceName");
```

Please note that you will need the necessary permissions in your Manifest.

See [Manifest Requirements](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html#manifest)